# Neo4j-Spring Data- How to avoid a nested property to be a node in a neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

- I am a java developer with 7 years of experience.
- New to Neo4j (using it with Spring Data)
- I am building a project in the education domain.
- I have a model (POJO), named Question.java which consists of a nested property (a list of) Answer.
- Answer.java has its own properties like id, ver, etc.

Now, when I save a Question entity by `repository.save(questionEntity);` it saves two nodes,
1 is `Question` and the other one is `Answer`.

I want to avoid `Answer` to become a node. And, its data should be stored in the Question node.

> **Reason** - Suppose, I have a Question entity which has 100 Answers and try to fetch Question data by
>   repository.findById(questionEntity.getId());, it will traverse
>   Question + Answer nodes (1 + 100 = 101). Not efficient.

Please see my POJOs below. Thanks in advance.

Additional question - What is better? Spring data repository functions like `findById`, `save`, etc or a `CYPHER` query?

```
@NodeEntity
public class Question {
    @Id
    private String cmsQId;
    private String type;
    private String difficultyLevel;
    private String questionId;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private List<Answer> answers;
}


public class Answer {
    private List<String> correctAnswer;
    private Feedback feedback;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mayank and welcome to SO.
You could go with an implementation of a `CompositeAttributeConverter` like in this [example](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/blob/8fc430d8f7d75b8bd4ec8ee3508be230a03d3bca/test/src/test/java/org/neo4j/ogm/domain/restaurant/LocationConverter.java#L26) but you will have to do the iteration for creating your collection by yourself (like appending numbers to the fields etc.)
In general I do not see the point why you want to store the `Answer` within the `Question` node. This is not really "graphy" and mapping e.g. 101 objects is not a big deal for SDN and a even much less for a graph database to provide the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried `CopositeAttributeConverter`, but I think it deals with Map<String, ?> and not List.
And, Json representations of Map and List are different.

P.S. Question and Answer nodes were just an example. I have multiple scenarios which will create millions of nodes in production.

I came to a solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54431684/neo4j-custom-converter-for-field-of-type-list by @LearnToLive using ConverterBasedCollectionConverter.

Do you an opinion on it?

Comment: I totally forgot about it, yes, if this solves your problem go ahead and use it.